# Real time face detection in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect face and only take a picture when the face is inside an elliptical shape that I created.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image/) and I already accomplish to detect the face, to draw the elliptical shape and to detect if the face is inside the shape, as you can see in this image:

[image]

In the above image: the red square is where the face detection algorithm is detecting the face and the elliptical shape is the one that I'd like the user to put his face inside its borders.

My problem now is how to do it in real time, in other words, when the UIImagePickerController opens, I'd like to draw the elliptical shape over it and only allow the user to press the button to take a picture if his face is inside it.

Is there any method that allow me to keep getting images before the user tap the take picture button so I can detect if his face is inside the shape area?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the simplest way would be to create a new image from within the elliptical shape and pass that for face detection instead of the entire image.